# Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) puppet:///modules/toolchain

Tags: directory, puppet

I am trying to write a simple resource to copy the content of a dire tory from puppet master to puppet agent.

```
file { "/usr/local/scaligent/" :
    ensure => 'directory',
    source => "puppet:///modules/toolchain",
    recurse => 'true',
    #owner => 'root',
    #group => 'root',
    #mode => '0755',
}
```

source is /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/files/toolchain/ in puppet master and destination is /usr/local/scaligent/ in puppet agent.

getting below error in puppet agent:

```
[~]$ sudo puppet agent -tv --noop
Info: Using configured environment 'production'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Retrieving locales
Info: Applying configuration version '1600365429'
Error: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/usr/local/scaligent/]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) puppet:///modules/toolchain
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.04 seconds
[ ~]$
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the Puppet [resource type reference](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.18/type.html#file-attribute-source), the form of a `puppet:` URI is

> ```
> puppet:///modules/<MODULE NAME>/<FILE PATH>
> ```

It refers to the content of a file or directory *in a module*, where Puppet will look for it in that module's `files` directory.  The file system path would be something like `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/<MODULE NAME>/files/toolchain`

The URI you are trying to use, `puppet:///modules/toolchain`, is not well formed, and the path you are trying to reference is not in any module's `files/` directory.

It would be conventional, albeit not required, to put the "`toolchain`" directory among the files of the module containing the resource declaration.  But then, it would also be conventional to put the `File` declaration in a class, in a module, which you have not done.  There are approximately zero circumstances under which it would be good style to declare that resource at top scope, as it appears you have done.